# Django - PostgreSQL ForeignKeyField and ManyToManyField performance

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I was once told to use foreign keys freely without consideration of the performance impact. This blog post says otherwise: http://bonesmoses.org/2014/05/14/foreign-keys-are-not-free/

Through searching, it seems that performance of DB relations is not something that is discussed frequently. From what little information I've found, it looks like foreign keys should be used where necessary, but avoided if it is optional. A `ManyToManyField` is effectively two `ForeignKeyField` operations, so the performance impact is equal to that of two foreign keys.

Is this information accurate? I don't have a big picture of just how significant or insignificant this performance impact is in practice, I would be really curious to see that.

Comment: Is your database worth anything if it is full of garbage and dangling pointers (i.e. references to things that no longer exist)? If you don't use real FKs then your database will be littered with broken garbage. Errors in your code are temporary, errors in your database tend to be permanent. Aim for data correctness and consistency first.

Comment: The cited text is complete nonsense, written by a application program coder with no apparent background in date modelling. Ignore it.

Comment: @wildplasser It's easier to trust him without an "air of mystery" surrounding his identity, so please don't be offended when I ask you for something to prove him wrong?

Comment: I fully agree with @muistooshort . In database design, asking for performance *first* raises red flags. Design for correctness+consistency+conciseness, and you will get performance for free. in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this information accurate?

Probably.

> I don't have a big picture of just how significant or insignificant this performance impact is in practice...

Well there is your first problem, as the saying goes [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Until you've completely profiled your system, its hard to say what if any impact optimising away Foreign Keys would do.

For example, consider a query that spends 1ms querying the database but 1 second performing other operations before delivering the content to the user after another second.

According to that article you linked, after some time, your query could be 95% slower, and run in nearly 2ms.

Which means you would optimise to save 1ms in a 2 second action, ultimately saving 0.001% of the effort.

Until you have thoroughly profiled your app and have determined that the time for foreign keys in the database is your most critical time loss, don't worry because the time to rewrite the Django DB abstraction layer, and the time saved if your data gets out of sync will probably orders of magnitude more than you saved.

Comment: I'm writing the model for the first time, so by asking this question I hope to avoid having to rewrite it. If  there's a 1% change that someone might benefit from a manytomany, whereas a foreign key would require a duplicate filefield somewhere, should I still make it manytomany?

Comment: If you are just starting foreign keys are the way to go from a purely ease of design point of view. There are tons of django optimisations that don't require non-use of Foreign keys. Consider that Instragram was built on django, and that is massive.

Comment: My gut feeling says that I should continue on the path that I'm on, but I won't do that because it seems that the majority of dev's (at least here on SO) don't agree. I don't have the experience or qualifications to dispute that, so I'll follow your advice in the best interest of my project. Thanks.